# How does pythons mktime work without timezone info?

Tags: python, time

I have working code. My question is *why* does this work?

```
#"04/13/05 2:30pm EDT" <- original date string
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
import time

T= time.struct_time((2005,4,13,14,30,0,0,0,1))
t = time.mktime(T)

print(t)
```

this prints

```
1113417000,
```

which according to an online converter, http://www.epochconverter.com/, prints

```
Your time zone: 4/13/2005 2:30:00 PM GMT-4
```

which is correct. My question is, how does it know the time was in EDT which is GMT-4? The last of the 9-tuple is "dst flag", but there are numerous timezones where DST is used. So how does it detect the correct timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It asks your operating system for that information, by way of the stdlib [C time functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions).

To quote the [`time` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html):

> Most of the functions defined in this module call platform C library functions with the same name. It may sometimes be helpful to consult the platform documentation, because the semantics of these functions varies among platforms.

You can pass in a -1 for the DST flag to have the library set it for you, see [`time.struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time). On my Mac OS X 10.7.5 setup, configured for the Europe/Oslo timezone, that gives me:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime((2005,4,13,14,30,0,0,0,-1))
1113395400.0
```

or, as 'translated' by epochconverter:

```
Your time zone: 4/13/2005 2:30:00 PM GMT+2
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=mktime#time.mktime) the function time.mktime(t) takes an argument (struct_time) expressed in local time, not UTC. Local time is taken from your operating system. You can see your local DST timezone with, for example, [time.tzname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time.tzname#time.tzname)